# For each property inside an object

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I have made this object to handle different options in my game.

```
var options = 
{
    Option: function(name, value, shortcut)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.shortcut = shortcut;
        this.texte = createElement("span",this.name + " : " + this.shortcut + "<br />");
        this.texte.parent("options");
        this.texte.id(this.name);
    },

    toggle: function(shortcut)
    {
        for (var o in this)
        {
            console.log(o);
            console.log(o.shortcut);
            if (o.shortcut == shortcut)
            {
                o.value = !o.value;
                if (o.value)
                {
                    o.texte.style("fontWeight","bold");
                    o.texte.style("color","green");
                }
                else
                {
                    o.texte.style("fontWeight","normal");
                    o.texte.style("color","red");
                }
                addText("Toggled"+ o.name);
            }
        }
    },

    initiate: function()
    {
        this.randomSpeed = new this.Option("Random Speed", true,"R");
        //this.randomSpeed.show();
        this.oneBall = new this.Option("Spawn one ball", false,"O");
        //this.oneBall.show();
        this.gravity = new this.Option("gravity", false,"G");
        //this.gravity.show();
        this.collision = new this.Option("Collision", false,"C");
        //this.collision.show();
        this.paintBackground = new this.Option("Paint mode",false,"P");
        //this.paintBackground.show();
        this.wall = new this.Option("Wall Collision", false,"W");
        //this.wall.show();
        this.unstuck = new this.Option("Unstuck", false,"U");
        //this.unstuck.show();
        this.blow = new this.Option("Mouse blow", false,"B");
        //this.blow.show();
        this.attraction = new this.Option("Mouse Attraction", false,"A");
        //this.attraction.show();
        this.superAttraction = new this.Option("Super attraction", false,"A");
        //this.superAttraction.show();
    }
};
```

The purpose was to handle all the differents options of the game in a way that I can add new options later and using the same code that already exists.

I use the creator function Option (inside the main object options) to instanciate new options as I implement them into the game.

my problem is with the `for (var o in this)` loop.

`console.log(o);` gives me the output I expect

> "Option" "toggle" "initiate" "randomSpeed" "oneBall" "gravity"
>   "collision" "paintBackground" "wall" "unstuck" "blow" "attraction"
>   "superAttraction"

but then `console.log(o.shortcut);` is not returning anything !
I checked in the [console of my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptLo0.png) , the object exists, and is instanciated correctly

Thanks !

————————————————————————————

Moreover, I’m looking for example of this kind of design, but I wasn’t able to find anything close to this. do you have example that I can refer to ? I’m really curious to see how it’s usually done.

Comment: Can you provide a working jsfiddle or a url where your code is deployed

Comment: This is the current version http://gosuness.free.fr/ballsOptions/
This the latest working version http://gosuness.free.fr/balls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the reference has been done to the member of the this object is wrong,

In the code `for (var o in this)` the variable o would refer to the index of the item in the `this` object so in order to refer the item you would have to call it using `this[o]` like when referring an array as shown below,

```
for (var o in this)
    {
        console.log(this[o].shortcut);
        if (this[o].shortcut == shortcut)
        {
            this[o].value = !this[o].value;
            if (this[o].value)
            {
                this[o].texte.style("fontWeight","bold");
                this[o].texte.style("color","green");
            }
            else
            {
                this[o].texte.style("fontWeight","normal");
                this[o].texte.style("color","red");
            }
            addText("Toggled"+ this[o].name);
        }
    }
```

Below is a working snippet,it does not contain all the features of the game or the code but it contains the code explained above and if you check the console the shortcut value will be printed right

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="game">
  </div>
  <aside>
   <p>
    Spawn ball: <br/>
    remove balls: <br/>
    reset:<br />
   </p>
     <p id="options">
      <span id="randomSpeed">Random velocity:<br /></span>
    <span id="oneBall">Spawn one ball:<br /></span>
    <span id="gravity">Gravity:<br /></span>
    <span id="collision">Collision:<br /></span>
    <span id="unstuck">Unstuck balls:<br /></span>
    <span id="paintBackground">PaintMode:<br /></span>
    <span id="wall">Walls:<br /></span>
    <span id="blow">Mouse Blow:<br /></span>
    <span id="attraction">Mouse attraction:<br /></span>
    <span id="superAttraction">Super attraction:</span>
    <br />
    <br />
   </p>

  </aside>
  <input type="text" onkeypress="keyPressed(event)">

<script>
var options = 
{
 Option: function(name, value, shortcut)
 {
  this.name = name;
  this.value = value;
  this.shortcut = shortcut;
 },
 
 toggle: function(shortcut)
 {
  for (var o in this)
  {
   console.log(this[o].shortcut);
   if (this[o].shortcut == shortcut)
   {
    this[o].value = !this[o].value;
    if (this[o].value)
    {
     this[o].texte.style("fontWeight","bold");
     this[o].texte.style("color","green");
    }
    else
    {
     this[o].texte.style("fontWeight","normal");
     this[o].texte.style("color","red");
    }
    addText("Toggled"+ this[o].name);
   }
  }
 },
 
 initiate: function()
 {
  this.randomSpeed = new this.Option("Random Speed", true,"R");
  //this.randomSpeed.show();
  this.oneBall = new this.Option("Spawn one ball", false,"O");
  //this.oneBall.show();
  this.gravity = new this.Option("gravity", false,"G");
  //this.gravity.show();
  this.collision = new this.Option("Collision", false,"C");
  //this.collision.show();
  this.paintBackground = new this.Option("Paint mode",false,"P");
  //this.paintBackground.show();
  this.wall = new this.Option("Wall Collision", false,"W");
  //this.wall.show();
  this.unstuck = new this.Option("Unstuck", false,"U");
  //this.unstuck.show();
  this.blow = new this.Option("Mouse blow", false,"B");
  //this.blow.show();
  this.attraction = new this.Option("Mouse Attraction", false,"A");
  //this.attraction.show();
  this.superAttraction = new this.Option("Super attraction", false,"A");
  //this.superAttraction.show();
 }
};

function keyPressed(e)
{
 if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == " ")
 {
   balls.splice(0,balls.length);
   background(70,20,150);
   addText("Reset");
 }
 else
 {
  console.log(""+String.fromCharCode(e.which))
  options.toggle(String.fromCharCode(String.fromCharCode(e.which)));
 }
}


options.initiate();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works like a charm !
What is it called when you use bracket to an object like you would do with an array ? I’m quite new to javascript, that’s not something I’ve learned yet.

Comment: That is the way we fetch items from an array

Comment: So when you do 'for ( x in blabla )' blabla is always considered as an array ?

Comment: generally you can only use an array or a json or a list in a for in loop